# How can I map through objects in angular with subscribe method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb, frontend

I am getting the locations as an array of objects from the nodejs backend. I have subscribed to it in the frontend in angular and it is returning the array of objects. How can I get the `name` property of each object? I am trying to do an auto filter with the autocomplete in angular.

COMPONENT file

```
getLocations(){
    this.locationService.getLocations().subscribe( (res )=> {
      console.log(res);
    })
  }
```

SERVICE FILE

```
  getLocations(): Observable<LocationTypes>  {
    const makeReqURL = `${this.apiURL}/`;
    const getLocations = this.http.get<LocationTypes>(makeReqURL, { })
    return getLocations;
  }
```

The image of the console log from the response in the front end.

[image]

Error after adding PIPE

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Screenshot with the undefined

[image]

ERROR Message

[image]

Comment: Do you mean to use `getLocations.pipe(map(lt => lt.name)).subscribe(name => console.log(name))`?

Comment: @Pieterjan I tried this and its returning undefined onthe conslose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: use pipe then tap to get names from response.

```
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

getLocations() {
    this.locationService
    .getLocations()
    .pipe(tap((response: any) => {
        response.map((data: any) => {
            return console.log(data.name);
        })
    }))
    .subscribe();
```

}

Comment: I tried this and its having an compiling errow with tap. Ill add an image in the question of the error message.

Comment: @Dave you have to import "tap" operator like this: import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators' at the top of our ts file

Comment: thank you, I tried that, I still get the 'undefined' in the console when i do 'res.name'. But when i conslo log only 'res' it shoes the full array of ogbects. I am still pretty new to anguler im not sure what im doing werong here.

Comment: Could you upload screen of your response?

Comment: @ I3artosh I uploaded an image.

Comment: @Dave I updated answer. Check it now. You are getting array of objects so you have to get inside into that array and recieve every single object. If you have problem with types for time being you can set for example data: any

Comment: @ I3artosh I tried that now its fiving andifferent error. I have added an image of that too

Comment: @ I3artosh I tried that now its giving a different error. I have added an image of that too. Not sure what im doing wrong in here.

Comment: @ I3artosh its saying map does not exist on the typr 'LocationTypes' which is my interface.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236492/discussion-between-i3artosh-and-dave).